# JavaScript var password error

Tags: javascript

i keep putting in this code, but every time i try it out, it lets me in whether or not it's the right password, rather than only letting me in if it's the right password. Can someone help with this issue?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--hide
var password;
var pass1="password1";
var pass2="password2";
password=prompt('Enter Password To View The Page',' ')
if (password==pass1||pass2)
alert('Correct password, Welcome.');
else{ 
window.location="http://www.google.com";
}

</script>
```

Comment: fyi: missing `{` after `if`

Comment: ";" is missing before if statement and compare pass1 and pass2 separately with password inside if block

Comment: Please view your console for errors and fix them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (password==pass1|| password == pass2){
    alert('Correct password, Welcome.');
}
else{ 
    window.location="http://www.google.com";
}
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/pw8n3jnm/)